# How can i give django formset instance

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

How can I give `formset` instance in Django formset? I created one question with 4 choices. Here choices are `choiceformset`. Now I want to open the created question form, then how can I pass the instance for the choice formset?

```
choice_instance=Choice.objects.filter(question=question_instance)
choice_formset=ChoiceFormSet(prefix='choice')
```

Comment: Each `choice` has  `question` primary key?

Comment: yes , Foreign key relation

Comment: Try this `choice_formset=ChoiceFormSet(prefix='choice', queryset=question_instance.choice_set.all())`

Comment: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'

Comment: Check this [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset)